# Is there a way to launch my app's system settings in a PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, application-settings, preferencescreen

I can launch the *device's* App settings activity from a PreferenceScreen.  When the activity loads, the activity displays a ListView with all of the different apps installed on the device. I can get to my app's system setting by scrolling through the list and clicking on the title of my app.

I make this happen in my preferences.xml file.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/system_settings_preference_title" >
    <intent android:action="android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Is there a way to launch *my app's* system settings rather than having to scroll through the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app's system settings can launched using the following intent where 
**com.myapp** is the app's package name found in the manifest file.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/system_settings_preference_title" >
    <intent android:action="android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"
        android:data="package:com.myapp"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```